# python substract months from datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to substract months and get a result in the form yyyymmdd.
To start I am given a string timestamp in sec, then here is what I'm doing:

```
>>> ts=1454284800
>>> billdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(time.strftime('%Y%m%d', time.gmtime(ts)), '%Y%m%d') - datetime.timedelta(5*365/12.0)
>>> billdate
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 22, 0)
>>>
```

In my snippet I substract 5 months, and get datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 22, 0).  I would like to get rid of the the hour 22 and get datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 0, 0).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what's stopping you from subtracting the 22 days?

Comment: Isn't the 22 something else? Hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point 1: 22 is not day. It is hours.

Point 2: If you want to get rid of hours and get datetime for 12:00 AM, then try this:

```
>>> billdate = datetime.datetime(billdate.year, billdate.month, billdate.day)
>>> billdate
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify fields of the datetime.datetime object, you need to use `replace`

```
billdate = billdate.replace(hour=0)
```

Quote from the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) wiki page

> `datetime.replace([year[, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[,
>   microsecond[, tzinfo]]]]]]]])`
>
> Return a datetime with the same attributes, except for those
>   attributes given new values by whichever keyword arguments are
>   specified